# google chrome console : net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, error-handling

**When i just normally open google chrome and then do inspect and then i got two errors in console... these are:**

`GET chrome-search://local-ntp/search-suggestions.js`

`net::ERR_FAILED`

**and**

`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-1+GSDjMMklBjZY0QiWq+tGupCvajw4Xbn46ect2mZgM=' 'sha256-2mX1M62Fd0u8q0dQY2mRsK5S1NS9jJuQAvyE8tD0dkQ=' 'sha256-EtIKSV82ixJHE3AzqhoiVbUGKG+Kd8XS0fFToow29o0=' 'sha256-QSyFltV9X3gkyBrg+SMfKvZNXmqPQc6K4B6OYhTuXmw=' 'sha256-ANdtIo91Yk/zh1YKZ+IXKP1pb00awOjEFMAUld02F6A=' 'sha256-CbH+xPsBKQxVw5d9blISLDeuMSe1M+dJ4xfArFynIfw=' 'sha256-lA+EURA/fC0TZq1ATYZvxIQHBc9iTAaBcI+dFMmTn9I=' 'sha256-ezOZE3GsFiiFM39LE8bQs5vdJyeJAqh3r+5jHc7863I='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: is it a specific website or does it happen everywhere?

Comment: it might be a chrome extension causing issues if it's everywhere, try disabling them and see if that fixes it